# How to navigate to new page in nw.js

Tags: nw.js

This is probably a simple question but I can't for the life of me find the answer online. I'm using nw.js and you specify the main html file in the package file. However, **how can I navigate in the same main window to a different html page?** The Window object doesn't seem to have any way to do this. It has an open() function but that opens a new window which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Ike10's answer, I was able to achieve this by simply coding:

```
location.href = './newHTMLDoc.html';
```

Maybe it is my version of NW, but my window object does not allow the code:

```
window.location.href
```

If you have a system Tray or other resources attached to the window, you'll still have those visually, but won't be able to use them anymore, forcing you to CTRL-ALT-DEL your way out of the mess. So be sure to remove resources as needed.

**EDIT - Some added info for passing data from one HTML doc to the next**

If you are like me and needed to pass data between pages, I found a simple solution for this. If we were creating a new window, you could use "emit" to pass data between windows. However, we are just changing .html documents, so we can't use that method.

Similar to a Singleton in Java, you can pass data between .html documents by creating a Javascript file with all the variables that you want to use throughout your application. As long as you have the Javascript file included in all the .html pages, these variables will be available to you.

I'm just learning Javascript, so this might be evident to many already, but just thought I would share this.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty new to nw.js, but I have found one solution. I believe the reason the window object does not work is because of javascript context. Nw.js has a node context and a webkit context. (More can be read here: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Differences-of-JavaScript-contexts). However, I solved my similar problem by making a separate js file for setting up a button to change the page.

index.js:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
    window.location.href = './OtherPage.html';
}
```

Make sure the require method is not used in the same js file as that would change the context.

Then load this into your html file.

index.html:

```
<script src="./path_to/index.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for questions or elaboration. I will try my best to help.